# Two-digit year in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Maybe this question is fool, but I didn't have found any answer that has satisfied me.

I have a SimpleDataFormat like:

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

And if I try to parse a date like: `10/10/15`

Then the Date result is for year 15, and not 2015.

Why the `parse` works in this case? I was expecting a `ParseException`

How I force the user to put year in 4 digit format? (Without `String.length()` please)

I'm using `setLenient(false)`

Comment: Well it seems you are indeed making it year `15` Is a valid date isn't?

Comment: @gtgaxiola no, I'm asking why putting year with two-digit the parse works. I want that it fails, I wanna force dates with four-digit years

Comment: Got it. Well `Date` has always been "iffy". If I may quote Pirates of the Caribbean the formatting "is more what you'd call 'guidelines' than actual rules".

Comment: From the [Javadoc of SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year) `For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D. `

Comment: @gtgaxiola thank you :) I think I will use String length.

Comment: @SubOptimal Maybe would make more sense if the Java expected 0012. Anyway, thank you so much. I think I will use string length

Comment: @JohnnyWiller For me this behavior is correct. `yyyy` - the digits to parse represents the literal year. `y` and `yy` - the digits needs a century as base, so the century is determined base on the rule `adjusting dates to be within 80 years before and 20 years after the time`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date is interpreted literally. Per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

> "For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the
> year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So
> using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D."

This is also why you didn't get the exception that you expected.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you say `dd/MM/yyyy`, java expects you to provide the 'full year', but its not necessary that it has to be 4-digit years. Its similar to `MMMMM` - this doesn't mean you want only 5 characters of the month, it means you want the full month name. I believe you will have to use String.length(), or you may parse it and check for date range.

Comment: And why java doesn't expect the 'full word year'? to specify year 15, I could simply write 0015. Why is not this way?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller Because... that's the way it was designed by the people at Sun / Oracle who built this. We can't tell you what they were thinking at the time...